# Transfer files from computer to raspberry pi using python script (Wifi connection - SSH setup)

Tags: python, pi-2, ssh, raspbian-stretch

I want to transfer text files or a complete folder containing text files from my computer to raspberry pi using a python script.

I am accessing my raspberry from the same computer (Using Putty) from where I have to copy files.

Now I am not understanding how to link the destination and source using python to make the transfer happen. I am beginner to linux and python. 
Anyone who can help me out?
would be thankful!!

Comment: Why don't you use `ftp` like the rest of us?

Comment: I want to copy files from 4 different computers to a hard disk mounted with raspberry pi. And it should be automatic e.g once a day at some specific time, my files starts copying from PC to the Hard disk. Makes sence?
I am not sure if I am doing it right or not as I am new to this :(

Comment: Then you should state this in your question. As it stands I don't know what you are asking.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, This program runs for me :)
import os, shutil
path = '/mnt/pc49/'
copyto= '/share/Festplatte/Saqib/'
files = os.listdir(path)
files.sort()
for f in files:
    src = path+f
    dst = copyto+f
    shutil.copy(src,dst)

print('Files Copied')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Non Python

The first way you could copy the file is over ssh.  If you've already got access to the Pi via Putty then the server-side is already working.  Just grab the `pscp.exe` binary from the [official site](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/%7Esgtatham/putty/latest.html).  **Watch out there's a similar one called `pSftp` which is probably not what you want**.

Then do the copy like this:

```
Windows> pscp c:\documents\info.txt pi@raspberry:/tmp/info.txt
```

There's a [step-by-step guide here](https://it.cornell.edu/managed-servers/transfer-files-using-putty).

For recursive copies of a directory, you sould use the `-r` flag:

```
Windows> pscp -r c:\documents\ pi@raspberry:/home/pi
```

This one copies the whole `c:\documents` folder to your home directory on the Pi.

The command uses encryption by default.

## Python

There's probably a number of ways to implement this, which could have pros or cons depending on your requirements.

### Natively

You could use Python's native low level networking interface, [`socket`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html) for device to device communication. One tutorial [demonstrates a configuration](https://www.bogotobogo.com/python/python_network_programming_server_client_file_transfer.php) to download files from EC2.  This would probably be benificial to learning Python.

Won't be encrypted by default.

### With a web framework.

If you want something that be accessed over HTTP, then you may look at a framework like Flask to implement a file upload facility. A [very basic script](https://gist.github.com/vulcan25/8e9444750426cdc7eb2cfd0a0f50a05c) I made can accept a single file-upload with the following `curl` command:

```
curl -i -X POST -F 'file=@upload_me.txt' "http://localhost:5000/upload" -H 'ContentType: multipart/form-data'
```

Or you could go further with it and add HTML templates, so it can be accessed through a web-browser, providing a file upload form.

This configuration is not encrypted (but can be with SSL certs from somewhere like Let's Encrypt, you'd also eventually run the application with `gunicorn` instead of Python, and preferably behind `nginx`).

Comment: Thanks, THe following code is working for me :)
import os, shutil
path = '/mnt/pc49/'
copyto= '/share/Festplatte/Saqib/'
files = os.listdir(path)
files.sort()
for f in files:
    src = path+f
    dst = copyto+f
    shutil.copy(src,dst)

print('Files Copied')

Comment: @SaqibShakeel I forgot NFS, which I assume one of these directories is mounted with?

Comment: yeah @v25 you are right :)